# Jenkins path in a pipeline

Tags: maven, jenkins, devops

How can I made my pipeline execute on

```
Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/
```

instead of

```
Jenkins in /opt/jenkins/workspace/
```

To make root pom readable. Because I am getting UNABLE TO READ POM error.

I am building a maven project through a pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the workspace and build directory path in `config.xml`

```xml
<workspaceDir>${JENKINS_HOME}/workspace/${ITEM_FULL_NAME}</workspaceDir>
<buildsDir>${ITEM_ROOTDIR}/builds</buildsDir>
```

Path of `config.xml` is **${JENKINS_HOME}/config.xml**

You can save the configuration and restart the jenkins server for the changes to get reflect.